# Извлечение часов из времени в python3

Tags: python-3.x

Добрый день!
В датафрейме df есть колонка 'Time' в формате str: '2:11:43', '10:19:34' и т.д. Нужно создать колонку 'Time_H', в которой в формате str были бы только часы: '2', '10' и т.д. Помогите плиз!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
time = '2:11:43'
time_h = time.split(':')[0]
```

Comment: Гениально! Спасибо!

Comment: При выполнении такого вот кода df.insert(loc=len(df.columns), column='Hours', value=df.Time.split(':')[0]) возникает такая вот ошибка: "AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'split' ". Как быть?

Comment: @Alex я вам показал как работать со строкой. `df.Time` – не строка. Я не эксперт в Pandas, но попробуйте посмотреть как устроена `df.Time.data` и где лежит строка, а уже к ней применяйте `split()`.

Comment: Решение через цикл ну очень долгое: df.insert(loc=len(df.columns), column='Hours', value=df.Time)
for i in range (0,len(df)):
    df.Hours[i] = df.Time[i].split(':')[0]

Comment: @Alex а как еще? Вам надо пройтись по всем строкам и достать часы. Но вы можете попробовать сделать так  – `df.insert(loc=len(df.columns), column='Hours', value=(i.split(':')[0] for i in range(df.Time)).next())`